# My program runs but I don't receive feedback on my console

Tags: python

I've ran this code and get no errors however the console won't display anything.

```
def smallest(x,y,z):
  if(x <= y and x <= z):
    min=x;
  else:
      min=z;
      return min
def average(x,y,z):
        avg=(x+y+z)/3
        return avg
```

Comment: You haven't written any code that calls those functions.  Add something like `print(smallest(1, 2, 3))` to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If this is all the code you have, at the end of the script, you need to call the functions with given arguments, and then if you want to see the results in the console, you must use the `print` function.

Example:

```
# Define your functions
def smallest(x,y,z):
  if(x <= y and x <= z):
    min=x;
  else:
      min=z;
      return min
def average(x,y,z):
        avg=(x+y+z)/3
        return avg

# Set variables if you wish
x = 1
y = 4
z = 10

# Call functions with arguments
smallest_answer = smallest(x,y,z)
average_answer = average(x,y,z)

# Print your results
print(smallest_answer)
print(average_answer)
```

You don't have to set variable, you can place your arguments straight into the functions when you call them, like this:

```
smallest_answer = smallest(1,4,10)
average_answer = average(1,4,10)
```